# DevOps Repos - How to stop visual studio showing red tick when file content did not change

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm using DevOps repos and Visual Studio 2019 for source control of a MySQL database. I generate the scripts for database objects each day to monitor the changes.

The problem I have is each time I generate the scripts for database tables, Solution Explorer shows red ticks(file is changed), but there is no change in the table create script. This is ruining the whole purpose of using a source control for my project.
I understand the file metadata may have changed but I don't worry about the file metadata changes.

> I don't want to see a red tick when the file content did not change. Is
> there a way I can tell Git/Visual Studio that check for differences in
> the file content only and ignore metadata changes.

gitattributes file is attached below. I'm using only .sql files in this project. The files were generated using a .NET console application and refreshes the folder which is under source control (Git Devops repos).

```
###############################################################################
# Set default behavior to automatically normalize line endings.
###############################################################################
* text=auto

###############################################################################
# Set default behavior for command prompt diff.
#
# This is need for earlier builds of msysgit that does not have it on by
# default for csharp files.
# Note: This is only used by command line
###############################################################################
#*.cs     diff=csharp

###############################################################################
# Set the merge driver for project and solution files
#
# Merging from the command prompt will add diff markers to the files if there
# are conflicts (Merging from VS is not affected by the settings below, in VS
# the diff markers are never inserted). Diff markers may cause the following 
# file extensions to fail to load in VS. An alternative would be to treat
# these files as binary and thus will always conflict and require user
# intervention with every merge. To do so, just uncomment the entries below
###############################################################################
#*.sln       merge=binary
#*.csproj    merge=binary
#*.vbproj    merge=binary
#*.vcxproj   merge=binary
#*.vcproj    merge=binary
#*.dbproj    merge=binary
#*.fsproj    merge=binary
#*.lsproj    merge=binary
#*.wixproj   merge=binary
#*.modelproj merge=binary
#*.sqlproj   merge=binary
#*.wwaproj   merge=binary

###############################################################################
# behavior for image files
#
# image files are treated as binary by default.
###############################################################################
#*.jpg   binary
#*.png   binary
#*.gif   binary

###############################################################################
# diff behavior for common document formats
# 
# Convert binary document formats to text before diffing them. This feature
# is only available from the command line. Turn it on by uncommenting the 
# entries below.
###############################################################################
#*.doc   diff=astextplain
#*.DOC   diff=astextplain
#*.docx  diff=astextplain
#*.DOCX  diff=astextplain
#*.dot   diff=astextplain
#*.DOT   diff=astextplain
#*.pdf   diff=astextplain
#*.PDF   diff=astextplain
#*.rtf   diff=astextplain
#*.RTF   diff=astextplain
```

Comment: That's a different kind of problem. Do you have a .gitattributes file? If so, can you add it to the question? Can you add more details about which (kind of) files are causing the issues?

Comment: Hi @jessehouwing please see the gitattributes file attached. I use only .sql files.

Comment: Don't see any issues here...